# How does skill damage scale in Cube World?

Tags: cube-world

The skill descriptions in Cube World outline effects and cooldowns, but they don't seem to outline damage.

How does skill damage scale in Cube World, and where can I see this scaling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your skills have a locked damage scaling. The damage you deal is tied to your equipment only. The only thing you get out of ranking most class skills is lower cooldown.

The exact damage scaling per skill is still unknown at this point.

Comment: By locked damage scaling, you mean skills do not scale based on your equipment? Equipment already scales very low with power so I'm surprised they don't make skills scale with equipment for a little extra umph.

Comment: by locked scaling I mean that a skill would do 150% damage no matter what level it is.

Comment: Ok, so they do scale with gear but never increase the percentage damage.